# solving $3\sin(x)^3 - 5\sin(x)\cos(x) + 2\cos(x)^2 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help solving this equation:
$$3\sin(x)^3   -   5\sin(x)\cos(x) +   2\cos(x)^2 =  0$$

I didn't find any place with this exact question.

Comment: "I didn't find any place with this exact question" That's not how problems are solved in general.

Comment: Well, I tried to solve this alone for a long time

Comment: Was the first term $3\sin(x)^3$, or $3\sin(x)^2$?

Comment: I think there might be a mistake in the book.... but lets say it is ^3 (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like $$3\sin^3 t -5 \sin t \cos t + 2\cos^2 t = 0 \tag 1$$ has four solutions in the closed interval $[0, 2\pi].$  one way to see this is to see $(1)$ as a quadratic equation in $x$ with the change of variables $x \cos t, y = \sin t.$ we now have $$2x^2 - 5y x + 3y^3 = 0 \text{ and } x^2 + y^2 = 1. $$  draw the graphs of $$x = \frac{5y \pm \sqrt{25y^2 - 24y^3 }} 4 \text{ and } x = \pm \sqrt{1-y^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, helped a lot.

Comment: @tanto30, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\sin(x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
 and
 $$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much ! However, I still can't get it right ):